# Which clojure jar contains clojure.contrib.io.Streams?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to compile some Clojure code to Java using the Clojure 1.2 compiler. I am including the Clojure and Clojure-contrib 1.2 jars in the classpath. When I do the compile it fails and I get the folowing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.contrib.io.Streams (io.clj:121)
```

: Has anyone seen this before?

Update:

Here is the line I use to compile my clj files:

```
java -cp "..\lib\h2.jar;..\lib\vaadin-6.4.4.jar;..\lib\clojure.jar;..\lib\clojure-contrib.jar;..\lib\wlfullclient-10.3.0.0.jar;..\..\..\..\..\jre1.6windows32bit\lib\rt.jar;."  -Dclojure.compile.path=cljclasses clojure.lang.Compile oe.main.oe-main
```

Comment: What are you trying to compile?

Comment: I am trying to compile clj files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use (compile 'oe.main.oe-main) from a clojure REPL using the same class path, and this works

Answer (score 2):

clojure.contrib.io.Streams is a protocol defined in [clojure.contrib.io](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/io.clj#L118)

To help you more you have to share more details about how and what you are trying to compile.

Comment: I am trying to compile .clj files. Everything works fine when I run the clj files using the same jar files

Comment: How are you trying to do it? leiningen? what is your project.clj?

Comment: java -cp "..\lib\h2.jar;..\lib\vaadin-6.4.4.jar;..\lib\clojure.jar;..\lib\clojure-contrib.jar;..\lib\wlfullclient-10.3.0.0.jar;..\..\..\..\..\jre1.6windows32bit\lib\rt.jar;."  -Dclojure.compile.path=cljclasses clojure.lang.Compile oe.main.oe-main

Comment: So I guess I mean to say that I am not uising Leningen or a Leningen project.clj

Comment: Do yourself a favor and try out leiningen or cake. Most likely your problems will disappear immediately.

Comment: I have since been told that I should use (compile 'oe.main.oe-main) from a clojure REPL using the same class path, and this works